# Python- How to prevent programs from opening unless the correct password is input

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, passwords

I've got a program that prevents distractions, IE: a video game, from opening between the hours of 12:00am and 8:00pm. It works great, however, I want to add some code to ensure that I cannot exit the python program, or process manually. This way, I can get a friend to choose a password which must be typed in order to exit the python script and allow the game to run.

I've tried getting the password input & requiring the password to exit the script, but the problem is I am still able to manually close the .pyw process with Ctrl+Alt+Delete.

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

i = 0

#Prevent Any Program before 8pm and after 11pm
#current date & time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()

si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
noProgram = 'Phoenix.exe'
noPrevent = "preventProgram.pyw"
while True:
    print(time(0,00))
    #If the time is between 12am and 8pm
    if now_time >= time(0,00) and now_time <= time(20,00):
        print("okay okay okay")
        subprocess.call('taskkill /F /IM '+ noProgram, startupinfo=si)
        sleep(1) # delay 1 seconds
##        print("It's between 12:00am & 7:59pm. Work Hours")
    if now_time >= time(20,00) and now_time <= time(23,59):
        print("Goodbye")
        exit()
##        print("it's after 8pm. Game On!")
    i += 1
i = 0
```

Comment: You can’t make a user process unkillable for some pretty obvious reasons.

Comment: if you have administrator privileges on a machine, then you can kill whatever you want.

If you don't have adminstrator privileges, then the script that is surveilling had to be started with administrator privileges.